# no compilation error but no output in turbo c++ 3.0

Tags: c, turbo-c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int *qs(int*,int,int);
int partition(int*,int,int);

void main()
{
    int arr[]={60,65,70,75,80,55,50,45,40};
    int p=0,q=8;
    int *sa;
    clrscr();
    sa=qs(arr,p,q);
    printf("\n After applying quick sort the array will be::\n");
    while(p<=q)
    {
        printf(" %d",*sa);
        sa++;
        p++;
    }
    getch();
}

int *qs(int *arr,int p,int q)
{
    int pos;
    if(p==q)
    {
        return(arr);
    }
    else
    {
        pos=partition(arr,p,q);
        qs(arr,p,pos-1);
        qs(arr,pos+1,q);
        return(arr);
    }
}

int partition(int *arr,int p,int q)
{
    int x,i,j,temp;
    x=arr[p];
    i=p;
    for(j=p+1;j<=q;j++)
    {
        if(arr[j]<=x)
        {
            i=i+1;
            temp=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[j];
            arr[j]=temp;
        }
    }
    temp=arr[i];
    arr[i]=arr[p];
    arr[p]=temp;
    return i;
}
```

The program is for quick sort using divide and conquer algorithm. While I am compiling this    code using turbo c++ 3.0, I'm not getting any error message but on running I'm getting only the black screen of console..I tried many times but not able to find any mistake.

Comment: And what happens in the debugger?  Almost certainly an infinite loop in there somewhere...

Comment: Please use GCC. Turbo C and Turbo C++ was used by dinos. Now they are extinct and so is this compiler.

Comment: ideone gives a segfault.

Comment: Its a typo. Look at the code again.

Comment: Sidenote: `void main()` is not supported by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

In your function `qs` check condition should be like this

```
  if(p>=q)
  {

    return(arr);
  }
```

else there will infinite recursive call to function `qs`

Answer (score 0):

Fix `qs()` :

There's an infinite recursion giving a segfault

```
int *qs(int arr[],int p,int q)
{
 int pos;
 if(p<q){
  pos=partition(arr,p,q);
  qs(arr,p,pos-1);
  qs(arr,pos+1,q);
  return(arr);
 }
}
```